# Papa.parse repeating csv parsing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Hi guys I've got a problem with parsing csv files in javascript. The following code is only used on load the HTML Page but I don't know why. Does somebody have got an idea?

Many thanks in advance!

```
 <script>
$(function test() {
        Papa.parse("lockedDevices.csv", {
                download: true,
                complete: function(results) {
                        console.log("Remote file parsed!", results.data);
                        $.each(results.data, function(i, el) {
                                var row = $("<tr/>");
                                if(el[0] == "Status")
                                    var color =" bgcolor='lightgrey'>"
                                if(el[0] == "Free"&&el[4]==" "&&el[5]==" ")
                                    var color = " bgcolor='lightgreen'>";
                                if(el[0] == "Locked")
                                    var color = " bgcolor='red'>";
                                if(el[0] == 'Free' && el[5]!=' ')
                                    var color = " bgcolor='yellow'>";
                                $.each(el, function(j, cell) {
                                    if (cell !== ""){
                                            row.append($('<td'+ color).text(cell));
                                    }
                                });
                                $("#lockedDevicesBox tbody").append(row);
                        });
                }
        });
})
setInterval(test(),1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned a named function to doc ready block and you are also trying to <strike>call</strike> run it in setInterval.

Instead i would say you put the function in the global scope and call it in doc ready within setInterval:

```
function test(){
     // test code
}

$(function(){
   setInterval(test, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work. The "test function" is only execute at reloading the page.

Comment: After testing around i got it. Your answer is correct for this problem. Thank you very much!